# Implement a login in SilverLight with WCF RIA

Tags: wpf, silverlight, authentication, silverlight-4.0, silverlight-5.0

I create a login page with SilverLight. But when users log in and then refresh page, the user is logged out! In other words, the SilverLight application restarts. How can I prevent this from happening on refresh?

Comment: Are you using forms authentication or windows authentication?

Comment: I use forms authentication

Answer (score 0):

I had also the same problem and after that I found some thing like this.

I create two pages With Login page and Dashboard Page.Here is the my Login page code. this will help you.

```
    private void BtnLogin_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        user.Username = TxtUsername.Text;
        user.Password = TxtPassword.Password;

        YourReference.YourReferenceServiceClient Service = new YourReferenceServiceClient();
        Service.LoginCompleted += Service_LoginCompleted;
        Service.LoginAsync(user);
    }

    void Service_LoginCompleted(object sender, LoginCompletedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Result == true)
        {
            Dashboard UserDashboard = new Dashboard(user);
            this.Content = UserDashboard;
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error Occured");
        }
    }
```

In WCF RIA service I created a method named as Login, Here is that code.

```
public bool Login(User LogUser)
{
    bool Status = false;

    //......Your Code.... if it is success return True otherwise false//

    return Status;
}
```

Comment: thanks a lot,but what are the "YourReference" and "Dashboard"?

Comment: "Your Reference" means the name of your service reference. You can replace it,with name of your Service Reference. Dashboard means when after user logged in to the system then system will be open up this page.Without Refreshing the Page. Got It? Dashboard is a Silverlight Page